# How do I resynchronise two git branches?

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches, `master`, and `test`.  When I try merging master into test, git thinks everything is up to date, but if I run `git diff master test`, I get a difference that I don't expect.  At this particular moment in time, I expect them to be completely identical.

I'm trying to figure out how to get these to be identical again.  One though I have is to delete the test branch and simply recreate it from master.  However, test is a shared branch, and exists also on the test server which automatically pulls the test branch based on commit hooks.  I expect that recreating the test branch will break the test server's attempt to pull?

Is there a cleaner way to resynchronise the two branches, or should I just bite the bullet and manually resync the test server here?

I'm also expecting a reasonable chance of having to do the same thing to the production branch at some point, which makes it all that much more important that I understand what I'm doing before going and doing it.

Note that if I ask git for any merges in one branch not in the other, it comes back with nothing - all merges are present.  It may have been a bad merge commit or something which got us to this point.

Comment: It is normal that you have difference between test and master, if you have a few commits in the branch test already. When you try to merge, what it actually tries to do is to merge the additional commits in the master branch after test branch is forked, into the branch of test.  If the master branch does not have additional commits, then there is nothing to merge (from master to test).

Comment: @GordonLiang - as I mentioned, at this particular point in time, I expect them to be identical because I've already merged everything over, only that git diff shows that they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is test based branched off master?

The reason I can think of is in your current scenario your master branch is behind test branch, meaning that test branch already has master's commits and it's own.

If you're using github or gitlab you could check your network graph to see what's up with them.

Also, make sure you didn't change your gitignore at some point.

If master is behind test, the only reasonable way I can think of you sync'ing them is by merging test into master, but that'd be when you want to take that to production.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, because it's not enough information for the complete answer, just few suggestions:

1. run `git log test --not master`. Thus you get the list of commits which are in `test` but not in `master`.
2. Reverse the arguments (`... master --not test`). Likely you'd get an empty list here
3. Certainly you shouldn't voluntarily delete published branches, thus you can create various problems for you and/or your co-workers. But if you clearly understand what the state of your repository is you could use `git push -f`. But think twice before forcibly override the state of a remote remository.
4. A good method to understand the current state of a repo is to visualize it e.g. with a local tool like `gitk --all` or a remote service (each popular hosting like github or gitlab has their own webtools for this).
5. I would suggest to use `git blame <file>` (or even `git gui blame <file>`) to understand from what commit a particular line comes from. Alternatively you may `git log -p` to get commits list with their changes.
6. In any case I would estimate the need of manual revamp the repo as extremely low. Likely you have a relatively simple problem, and simply don't have enough information to completely understand it.